# May one say kaddish for a non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, history, gentiles, death, kaddish

I [have read](http://forward.com/articles/166698/abraham-lincoln-the-jew/?p=all) that Jews recited kaddish on behalf of Abraham Lincoln after he was assassinated. What is the halachic basis for this and has kaddish ever been said en-masse on behalf of other non-Jews?

Comment: Kaddish for a Gentile
* Sefer Chasidim, no. 790
* Responsa Maharik, no. 44
* Yechaveh Da'as 6:60 
* Be-Ohalah Shel Torah 1:60

Answer (score 8):

Ha-Rav Ovadiah Yosef rules that it is permissible and proper to recite Kaddish (Shut Yechaveh Da’at 6:60).

Comment: regarding the mishna isn't it the case that his slave was freed (and thus Jewish) before he passed away?

Comment: No, I do not think that he was ever freed. I might be mistaken, though. I think the story goes something like Rabban Gamliel accidentally knocked out the slave's tooth and rejoiced at finally being able to free him, but Tabi elected to remain a slave as he has the right to do.

Comment: That's very unlikely. The practice of saying kaddish for the deceased well post-dates the Gemara.

Comment: @DoubleAA, You're right. I must have misremembered the Mishna. Mishna Berachot 2:7 says that Rabban Gamliel accepted condolences for his slave as if he were Jewish. I'd say that's a similar situation that might argue for saying kaddish for a non-Jew, but that's not up to me to decide. I have removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I was under the impression that the gemara makes reference to saying "Yehei shmeih" to ease the neshama's transit to 'Olam Habah. I do not know the daf or masechet though.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I suppose that is interesting, but there isn't much I can do with that information unless you give me a concrete reference.

Comment: @DoubleAA, The Siddur Bnei Ashkenaz cites Rashi to Masechet Shabbat (Bavli) on page 25, although no daf is given.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Rashi well post-dates the Gemara...

Comment: @DoubleAA, Very true, but the gemara itself is the source in question, I was merely reporting that Rashi's commentary is the vehicle used for this particular piece.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Perhaps, but we can't tell till we see the actual gemara inside.

Comment: Can you please clarify the top comment? Mishna Berachot 2:7 says that Rabban Gamliel accepted condolences for his slave "as if he were Jewish," but top comment from user2110 says a freed slave is "thus Jewish," i.e. all freed slaves are considered Jews with or without conversion. Are they considered Jews or just considered "as Jews" int terms of similarity of circumstance only, since Jews were also once slaves who were freed? Or is a Muslim slave of Isis who gets freed now considered a Jew because he's a freed slave? That's how the top comment reads but I can't recall this in my studies.

Answer (score 3):

Piskei Teshuvos rules that not only is it permitted but even desirable for a Ger Teddek to say Kaddish for a gentile parent. He should nevertheless do it discreetly due to the fact that it might be strange in the eyes of most people.

The earliest source for saying kaddish for a Gentile is in Sefer Chassidim where we find that kaddish can be said for a gentile who rescued Jews in dire times. Later authorities expanded this ruling for a convert to say kaddish for his non-Jewish parents.
I found a responsa online where the Rov suggested having in mind the meaning of the kaddish and that it should be said with all Jews in mind as well.

For practical applications, please consult your personal rabbi.

Sources:

ראה ס״ח תשצ: אם יש נכרי שעשה טובות ליהודים יכולים לבקש להקב”ה שיקל בדינו וכן יכולים לבקש על מומר שעשה טובה ליהודים וכן אמר ר’ יוחנן על חרבונא זכור לטוב לפי שדבר על המן. אבל נכרי רע וכן מומר רע אין לבקש עליו ויצחק אמר על עשו יוחן רשע (ישעי’ כ”ו י’) והשיב לו בל למד צדק (שם) וכו’ וגר המבקש על אביו ועל אמו לא יועיל להקל מדינם. (ומש״כ שם בגר, היינו שאינו מועיל כ״כ, או כשלא עשה אביו טובה ליהודים, דהא לא גרע משארגוי שעשה טובה ליהודים). ובשו״ע או״ח תרצ, טז: וצריך שיאמר: וגם חרבונה זכור לטוב.

ובשו”ת זקן אהרן ב, פז: “ולפ”ז אין מקום לחייבו באמירת קדיש, דאי מטעם כיבוד אב וכמ”ש המעבר יבק הטעם דאמירת קדיש הבן על האב משום שחייב בכבודו, והא הכא אינו אביו ואין מחויב לכבדו, ובלא”ה נמי מה תועלת בקדיש זה דכל עיקרו לא בא אלא משום דברא מזכה אבא וע”י שהבן יקדש שם שמים ברבים מעלין נשמת אביו מדין גיהנם, אבל גר דכקטן שנולד הוא ואינו אביו כלל לא שייך לומר דברא זה מזכה אביו כיון שאינו בנו וכו’. אכן שוב ראיתי דבאמת יש מקום לחייב לגר באמירת קדיש, דהנה הרמב”ם בפ”ה מהלכות ממרים הי”א כתב וז”ל הגר אסור לקלל אביו העכו”ם ולהכותו ולא יבזוהו כדי שלא יאמרו באנו מקדושה חמורה לקדושה קלה שהרי זה מבזה אביו אלא נוהג בו מקצת כבוד אבל בעבד אין לו יחס אלא הרי אביו כמו שאינו אביו לכל דבר אף על פי שנשתחררו עכ”ל. וכו’ יהיה איך שיהיה הטעם ברמב”ם אבל עכ”פ שפתיו ברור מללו דגר חייב לנהוג כבוד באביו, וכיון שאמירת קדיש מטעם כבוד הוא וכמ”ש המעב”י, ולא עוד אלא דמי שמונע מלומר קדיש הרי הוא כמבזה לאבותיו ממילא שגם הגר מחויב לומר קדיש. והרי הראיתי בזה דיש פנים לצדד מצד ההלכה דיש גם חיוב לכבדו ולומר קדיש, אכן מפני שאין להורות הוראה שנראה תמוה לרבים, ונקל לשער שכל השומע הוראה כזאת יתפלא ע”ז, ובשגם אשר לבנו אטום וסתום מלהבין סוד עליית נשמה ותיקונה ע”י אמירת קדיש דוקא, ואם מפני שברא מזכה אבא וחולקין כבוד לנשמת האב אם הבן עושה מצוה, ומכריזין לפניו ראו שזה ילד וגידל ברא טבא דכוותי’, א”כ למה אמירת קדיש דוקא, והלא מי ימחה בידו ללמוד תורה או להגיד מזמורי תהלים, ובשגם אשר בעיקר הדברים שכתבתי יש לפקפק כיון דכיבוד לאב עכו”ם הוא רק כדי שלא יאמרו באנו וכו’ ולכן סגי גם בכבוד כזה שבין העכו”ם נוהגים, אבל אמירת קדיש שביניהם לא נהיגי בזה, מה שייך לומר בזה שלא יאמרו באנו מקדושה חמורה כו’. ולכן כיבוד כזה שאצלם לא נהוג לא שייך לחייבו לגר, ועוד דעיקר מעלת הקדיש שזהו תיקון לנשמת האב, ומי בא בסוד ד’ לידע אם לנשמת עכו”ם נמי כן, ואם כי חסידי אוה”ע וגם בינונים יש להם חלק לעוה”ב וכמ”ש הרמב”ם בפ”ג מהלכות תשובה מדחז”ל הוציאו רק לבלעם שרשע הוא כמ”ש בסנהדרין דק”ב מכלל דשארי אוה”ע שאינן רשעים כבלעם יש להם חלק לעוה”ב, אבל אכתי קשה להגיד בזה מהו השארת הנפש ועוה”ב של נכרי, ולכן לדעתי כל גר שחושש לעשות כדין ולומר קדיש ברבים, יוכל לנהוג ללמוד גם לומר תהלים תחת קדיש, וממ”נ אם למעלה יוצא מזה תיקון לנשמת אביו הרי טוב ובא”ל למודו יהא קודש לו לעצמו, ובדרך הזה יוכל לפעמים להתפלל בפני העמוד וגם לומר קדיש באופן שלא יהא בולט שמחמת אבילותו עושה כן לתקן נשמת אביו הגוי, ויהי’ מונע בהנהגה כזאת מדבת רבים שיבואו לידי גיחוך וליצנות, שההפסד יהי’ מרובה על השכר, אבל כשהוא לעצמו לא באופן בולט כדאי מאוד לחזור לומר קדיש וגם ללמוד ולחוש למה שכתבתי כי יש מקום לצדד ולומר שמחויב מדינא.

וראה גם שו”ת ממעמקים ג, ח. שו״ת יחוה דעת, ו, ס.

Sources:

https://asktherav.com/19782-my-non-jewish-father-passed-away-can-i-say-kaddish-for-him/#more-19607
http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4999 ; http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=37 https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2972 https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/1681 https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2995

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Ephraim Oshry in Responsa from the Holocaust #85 allowed survivors to say Kaddish for the gentile woman who had hid them in her house.  With justification, it seems allowed.

See there for more sources.

Comment: Are you referring to Shut Mimaamakim? There are 5 volumes of it. Which volume is this in?

Comment: @DoubleAA The English edition is in one volume, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Eliyashiv in Ashrei Haish 91:1 holds that a convert may say kaddish for his father who passed away.