# Are Bnei Noach welcome as participants in Orthodox Synagogues?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, noahidism

Are Bnei Noach normally allowed to take part in any of the liturgy in Orthodox synagogues? For example: responding to Torah blessings, singing Adon Olam, reciting Kaddish (except Mourner's Kaddish), etc. Obviously there would be no Aliyah. What are normally the rules regarding Noachide participation?

Comment: The source would probably be the way we treat a "Ger Toshav" as that is the closest equivalent.

Refer to: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/what-is-a-ger-toshav

Comment: I read the link, CC. It does not address this issue.

Comment: You might as well ask can any non-Jew answer amen to a bracha. Do you mean singing Adon Olam with the rest of the congregation or leading it? I do not understand what you mean by reciting kaddish. I think you need to make yourself clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a gentile pray in a synagogue?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/can-a-gentile-pray-in-a-synagogue)

Comment: Re - "reciting Kaddish (except Mourner's Kaddish)" - 1 - I think Gentiles CAN recite Mourner's Kaddish (there may be a MY question about that; have to hunt.) 2- All other types of Kaddish are recited by the *chazzan* who must be Jewish.

Comment: sabbahillel, I meant singing Adon Olam along with the congregation. I also mean praying the congregational prayers and making the congregational responses with the congregation. I hope this helps.

Comment: Psalms are almost certainly allowed.

Comment: @sabbahillel I think the OP is asking about whether the he can answer "Amen" to blessings and recite along with prayers, not whether he can be the chazzan.

Comment: @DanF [There is a question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28028/1713) about saying kaddish for a non-Jew, but I think there is a question about a non-Jew himself saying kaddish.

Comment: @Daniel I believe that there are a few prayers that a Gentile should not say, but they seem to be few. Offhand, I can't imagine that Kaddish would be one of them. The majority of it's phrasing relates to G-d's glory and kingship, which is a Noachide belief, anyway. And, I can't see a problem with a Gentile wishing "Peace on all Israel". Would only a lot more Gentiles say this!

Comment: @DanF that previous comment was a typo on my part. I meant I _don't_ think that there is a question (on Mi Yodeya) about a gentile saying kaddish.

Comment: @Daniel Ah! Hanukah hangover, I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the specific question asked at the end of the comments section, (see there) i see no reason why a Ben Noach would not be allowed to join in Adon Olam or answering Amen to any blessing, which is like saying "I agree."

Answering Kaddish seems to be the same. In Aleinu, we look forward to the messianic times when every person will accept the Oneness of haShem. Why not say it a few years (or days!) early?

As for saying those parts of davening (prayer) that come from Tehillim (Psalms), I think it would be alright.

As for making some blessings, it would seem not. Certainly (1)those that say "kiddishanu"(He has commanded us) or (2)in the Amidah, which starts with "...G-d of our fathers," which would not be true. This has been discussed in responsa and Halacha regarding (1) a woman taking a lulav&etrog; &(2) a Ger Tzedek & has been decided that (1) the custom has been established that women do this mitzvah so she can say "He commanded us" and (2) a Ger is like a newborn (Jewish) child and should say "Our father"(and not skip the phrase). Both these don't apply to a non-Jew. 
It would seem that a non-Jew could say blessings that are praises (for food, Asher Yatzar, most morning blessings, etc.)

Rav Moshe Feinstein, Ztz"l, Igros Moshe, 2/25, states that a non-Jew is not commanded to pray but if he chooses to pray, he would receive reward like one who is "eino Metzuveh v'oseh,"(not required but volunteers). With that in mind, saying the Amidah seems appropriate as long as one would skip the phrase "G-d of our fathers."

Comment: Hi RYMV. We don't know you that we should trust your instincts or opinions as reasonable, accurate, or even Jewish. Please [edit] in sources to support your claims. Doing so will greatly improve this post's value to the community.